# SVN Branch Viewer

Tags: svn

Is there is a tool for SVN that visually shows how branches are related? I've got a couple dozen branches and it isn't clear how they were created from one-another.

EDIT: I'm not looking for indivial files, I need to look at whole branches. For example:

[image: Branching guide from TFS docs]

Answer (score 2):

I know only of a non-free one: [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/features):

[image: SmartSVN branches]

But the [graph feature of the latest TortoiseSVN 1.7](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) can help too:

> Can create a [graph](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/bigpicture.html#revisiongraph) of all revisions/commits. You can then easily see where you created a tag/branch or modified a file/folder

[image: TortoiseSVN graph]

Since a branch is a directory in SVN, you can display the its graph and see at the path of the revision of its origin, to get an idea of the "parent" branch.

Comment: That sounds like it is going to be just as tedious as checking the log for each directory.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: yes, which is why I mentioned smartSVN first (doing precisely what you mention in your edit minus the merges of course).